# SUM all cells of type defined in separate column?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with a data set that looks something like:

```
Actual Monthly Expenditure  £0.00
Budgeted Expenditure        £200.00
Monthly Variance            -£200.00
Budget Transfers        
Actual Monthly Expenditure  £300.00
Budgeted Expenditure        £300.00
Monthly Variance            £0.00
Budget Transfers    
Actual Monthly Expenditure  £112.90
Budgeted Expenditure        £180.00
Monthly Variance            -£67.10
Budget Transfers    
Actual Monthly Expenditure  £1,174.80
Budgeted Expenditure        £1,174.80
Monthly Variance            £0.00
Budget Transfers    
Actual Monthly Expenditure  £0.00
Budgeted Expenditure        £30.00
Monthly Variance            -£30.00
Budget Transfers
```

I need a function to add up all the actual expenditure and minus it from the budgeted expenditure.

Any pointers on how to do this?

I tries looking at DSUM functions but couldn't find an example (or get one to work through testing) that did exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Use `SUMIF()`. See http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx.

Suppose your first column is `transferType` and second column is `amount`, then you can write

```
SUMIF(transferType,"Budgeted Expenditure",amount)
- SUMIF(transferType,"Actual Monthly Expenditure",amount)
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative may be to use the function SUMPRODUCT(), which allows to use filters as well.

Suppose on your worksheet

- the named range TransferType refers to the range A1:A20, and
- the named range TransferAmounts refers to the range B1:B20.

Then the following function will take the difference of the Actual Monthly Expenditures and and the budgeted expenditures:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
             (
               (TransferTypes = "Actual Monthly Expenditure") - 
               (TransferTypes = "Budgeted Expenditure")
             ) * 
             (TransferAmounts)
           )
```

If you are not accustomed to working with named ranges, the following will do exactly the same:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
             (
               ($A$1:$A$20 = "Actual Monthly Expenditure") - 
               ($A$1:$A$20 = "Budgeted Expenditure")
             ) * 
             ($B$1:$B$20)
           )
```

If find it to be more intuitive to work with SUMPRODUCT() than the SUMIF() or SUMIFS() functions as it is clear to see from the function how the filter works. If you are not up to speed with the workings of SUMPRODUCT(), then read up on it in the [excellent article](http://www.excelhero.com/blog/2010/01/the-venerable-sumproduct.html) by Daniel Ferry.

Answer (score 0):

For your question I would choose @pearpies solution but given the nature of your data I would expect to find it very useful to have this in PivotTable format, where answers in addition to your question would be equally readily available.

A PT as below not only shows the requested result (-£297.10) but other aggregated information - and is easy to adjust for alternative views of the data source:

[image: SO19942047 example]